# How to get the substring between ":"

Tags: java, regex, substring

Suppose I have a string like this one:

> "(...) Example: Hello world. Description: Here is a long text, with words and
>   ponctuation. This is the part I need. This part I do not need: End of
>   the example. (...)"

How do I get only this substring:

> Here is a long text, with words and ponctuation. This is the part I need.

Where I wrote (...) is the continuation of the string, I'm dealing with a long text but want to get just the **Description** in this case.

I want everything (words, dots, commas, etc) between "Description:" and the word(s) before the next ":"

The exact example:

Job Title: Java Programmer Date: 18/04/2014 Quantity: 4 vacancies Job Description: Implement systems under a software factory, work with Agile, Spring, Hibernate and GWT. Higher Education in computer science. TDD course. Knowledge in agile methodologies, described activities, TDD and BDD. Having good communication. Notes: Benefits: Healthcare / Medical Group, Ticket-feeding, Transportation voucher scheme Hiring: CLT (Permanent) Hours: Monday to Friday from 8am to 17h30 with 1h30 lunch.

I need:

Implement systems under a software factory, work with Agile, Spring, Hibernate and GWT. Higher Education in computer science. TDD course. Knowledge in agile methodologies, described activities, TDD and BDD. Having good communication.

The substring after "Description:" and before "Note:" in this case, but this second word (Note:) can be any word(s). That's why I thing I need a regular expression, but don't know what is it.

Comment: can you put the exact example, without notations? thanks.

Comment: Use the method `substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` that is used for a String.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing this. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know the index. I need to do this with a regex, I think.

Answer (score 3):

```
String original = "This is a string: Here is what you want: Maybe you want this too?";
int firstColon = original.indexOf(':');
int secondColon = original.indexOf(':', firstColon+1);
if (secondColon != -1) {
    String parsed = original.substring(firstColon+1, secondColon);
} else {
    //2 colons not found
}
```

The above code finds the first index of a `:` character and stores it. It then finds the next `:` after the original. If the second colon was found (the `if` statement), the string is parsed and stored. `String.substring` is inclusive of the first index and exclusive of the last. To trim off any leading or trailing spaces add `.trim()` to the end of the parsed line. To only scan for the first colon, use the following. (This trims the string)

```
String original = "This is a string: Here is what you want: Maybe you want this too?";
int firstColon = original.indexOf(':');
if (firstColon != -1) {
    String parsed = original.substring(firstColon+1).trim();
} else {
    //One colon not found
}
```

Something to note is that Strings in java are immutable. original.substring will not change original, only return a new String of the substring characters.

Comment: That's good. There's only one problem. I don't want the word(s) before the second colon. The substring I need is after "Description:", it finishes with a dot, then it come some word(s) I don't want and the next colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method, like this:

```
String[] sentences = "This is a : test".split("[:]");
```

The parameter passed to the split method is a regular expression, and returns an array of Strings which every division.

For example, the method shown above will return the following output:

```
sentences[0] will be This is a"
sentences[1] will " test"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with **(<=)jdk1.6**, and as you said the text could be **long**, I won't use `substring()`,  to avoid the the potential memory problem.

regex is straightforward to get things between two `:` :

with group: `:([^:]*):`

without group: `(?<=:)[^:]*`